# Draw on top of suspended full-screen Direct3D app

Tags: direct3d, directx-9

Currently, I am able to hook onto Direct3D application and draw custom stuff onto its surface. However, I would like to suspend this application and then draw something else.

Is this even remotely possible to do so? Like creating another my own Direct3D window on top of that application?

I'm targetting only Windows 7, but the application I want to draw on is using only DirectX 9.

The problem is that I have very little experience with DirectX in general.

Answer (score 1):

Sort of.

You're working with two different elements here, one quite large and but not particularly complex: hooking D3D. The other ("suspending" the app) is simple within that, but you don't quite want what you think you want.

To hook D3D, by the simplest method, you need to intercept the call to `CreateDirect3D9` and return your own `IDirect3D9`, which later creates and returns your own `IDirect3DDevice9`. This will give you full control over the app's render process.

In order to "suspend" it, you need to wait for the desired trigger, then in your `IDirect3DDevice9::Present`, call your own event loop. This will, for all intents and purposes, suspend *execution* of the original app's *code*, but not the process itself (allowing your code and event loop to process). There will be some limitations of this, and you may not be able to consume window/Windows events (simply), but it will give you full control and effectively pause the original app.

Note, however, that you must intercept and reroute execution in every *thread* you want to "suspend," it's only specific to a single thread and you don't want physics or AI crunching on while render and UI are paused.

You need to perform your overlay drawing, whatever that may be, during your loop or your `IDirect3DDevice9::Present` hook, then call the real device's `Present` method as needed. If you want to run multiple frames of your overlay, then call the real `Present` repeatedly before returning from your `Present`. Tweak as necessary. Rendering here is done pretty much normally (check out general D3D tutorials for that), but there is one major catch: the device's state is unknown and may be incompatible, but **must** be "untouched" on return. This is handled simply by caching an `IDirect3DStateBlock9` [created from the device](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) immediately after creating it. In your `Present` hook, create *another* state block with the state on entrance, restore the clean state block, run your code, then restore the entrance state block. You can work with any states, off a fresh slate, without damaging the device's state (I use this in practice, in works great).

If you want some rather extensive examples of how this works, I'd suggest checking out [the Voodoo Shader project](https://github.com/peachykeen/VoodooShader), which has full D3D8 and 9 hooks, including everything needed for overlays [/shameless own-project promotion]. Feel free to reuse any of the concepts, or comment with further questions; this certainly isn't all the details that may be useful to you.

Comment: So when I intercept CreateDirect3D9 function, that thread which called it will be the render thread, thus when I will want to suspend the application, I suspend all its threads but this render thread, right?

Comment: Typically, yes. However, it is possible for the object or device to be created with a thread-safe flag, and later be used from multiple threads. In practice, this isn't particularly common, but if you run into it a few `Interlocked...` calls and some lock variables will sort things out. Try to avoid anything thread-unsafe, and make sure your loop is protected. You may want to run your target app through a debugger and see how many threads are in play; make sure not to count DirectInput polling threads and DirectSound play threads, as these don't (quite) belong to the app.

Comment: I stand corrected, I guess I'm a bit retro since you can see when those pages were created ;)

Comment: @tcables No worries, it looks like most of this isn't incredibly well documented, at least not lately (I've been doing it for a while, so I'm surely biased toward thinking it simple). Looks like someone needs to write more up-to-date tutorials. /me doesn't really want to

Comment: peachykeen: What do you mean by "reroute execution in every thread"? Can't I just suspend them in usual manner (e.g. SuspendThread) ?

Answer (score -1):

This is a **very complex** thing to accomplish, as it is very much a hack to do so. The only people you see doing such things are steam, teamspeak, xfire, fraps, and a few hard-core devs.

There are kits out on the internet that show you have to inject a DLL into the memory space of the target application to achieve such a feat, and methods such as proxy DLLs.

Proxy DLL:
http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/g-m/directx/directx8/article.php/c11453

Injection:
http://www.progamercity.net/d3d/372-c-directx9-0-hooking-via-detours.html

Good luck, this will take you a while.

Comment: Hooking D3D, due to how COM objects are handled, isn't incredibly complex. It does take a lot of code, but it's all very stock and well-documented (due to dozens of projects doing it). Injecting a DLL isn't particularly hard either, with a half-dozen ways of doing it. Using Detours is a **very** bad idea, as it has numerous bugs and incompatibilities (most notoriously, crashing any 32-bit process running on a 64-bit system). If detouring is needed, EasyHook is significantly better, including better thread and recursion handling. No hacks or risky code at all is needed for this, ...

Comment: As I said, I am currently able to draw an overlay on the designated Direct3D app - I already have the code to hook and draw the overlay working.

Comment: as COM's design forces abstraction of interface and object and interception in no way violates that handling. The only thing of note is handling reference counting properly, which is easy, but not all D3D functions and methods have their behavior w.r.t. reference count documented. Both the links are out of date, not entirely accurate, and **do not** follow best-practices for handling this.